# What IP HAPROXY adds to the header?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, haproxy

We need to specify the mode in the haproxy service description in docker compose file using long syntax:

```
services:
    haproxy:
        ports:
            # long port syntax https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-1
            - target: 80
              published: 9763
              protocol: tcp
              mode: host
```

After reading some articles online, I added following to haproxy's backend section:

```
backend api
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Client-IP %[src]
    http-request add-header X-FrontEnd-IP %[dst]
```

Also, I start containers by running `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack` command.

Now note that when I run `hostname -I` command, I get following output

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.0.102 172.18.0.1 172.17.0.1 172.19.0.1 192.168.49.1
```

Also my wifi settings shows IP `192.168.0.102`:

[image]

I am able to access the app from the same laptop on which it is running using three IPs: `http://172.18.0.1:9763/`,  `http://127.0.0.1:9763/` and `http://192.168.0.102:9763/`.

- **Accesing the django web app from laptop using all above three URLs give following output**

  In python code, I see different header values as follows:

  ```
   'HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP' : '172.18.0.1,172.18.0.1'
   'HTTP_X_FRONTEND_IP' : '172.18.0.9'
   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' : '172.18.0.1'
  ```

  And `172.18.0.1` gets logged to database, as I am logging `'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'`.
- **Accesing from tablet using** `http://192.168.0.102:9763/login`

  My tablet is also connected to the same router as my laptop running the app. From tablet, I am able to access the app using url `http://192.168.0.102:9763/login`, but not using `http://127.18.0.1:9763/login`. When accessed using `http://192.168.0.102:9763`, various headers have following values:

  ```
   'HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP' : '192.168.0.103,192.168.0.103'
   'HTTP_X_FRONTEND_IP' : '172.18.0.9'
   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' : '192.168.0.103'
  ```

  And `192.168.0.103` gets logged to database, as I am logging `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`.

My concern is that the IP of my laptop's WiFi NIC is `192.168.0.102`, but it ends up logging `172.18.0.1`. Shouldn't it be logging `192.168.0.102` (similar to how it logs `192.168.0.103` for laptop) ? Also why it adds `172.18.0.1` to headers in case of laptop? And how can I make it log `192.168.0.102` when app is accessed from laptop?

Comment: i shared the solution. hope it will help you. feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

when you access your application from your laptop (the same machine where the application is running), the traffic is not going through your WiFi network interface (which has the IP address 192.168.0.102). Instead, it's being routed through the Docker network, which is why you see the Docker network IP address (172.18.0.1) in the logs.

This is normal behavior. When you access a local service on the same machine, the traffic doesn't need to go out to the network, so it doesn't use the network interface's IP address. Instead, it uses the loopback address (127.0.0.1), or in this case, the Docker network's IP.

You could address this issue by running a reverse proxy on an external device, which would then forward the traffic back to your laptop.

Using macvlan docker network driver for resolution will also not work in this case.